# rails 3: what does the h() in "content_for(:title) { h(page_title.to_s) }" do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

My app is using a view helper than adds a layout helper that contains the code

```
content_for(:title) { h(page_title.to_s) }
```

and I'm trying to modify it somewhat but have no idea what the h() means?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is an ERB method to escape the HTML. See [the ERB docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/erb/rdoc/classes/ERB/Util.html#M000869) for more info about it.